# Understanding the logic of an add to an array method

Tags: java

This method is used to insert the element toAdd as the new first element of the array arr, shifting all of the current elements over to make space. The original last element of the array will just be lost. The method has no return value and if the array has no elements it should have no effect.

```
public static void insert(int[] arr, int toAdd){

    if(arr.length > 0) {

        for(int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; --i) {
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
        }
        arr[0] = toAdd;
    }
}
```

I understand the part about if(arr.length > 0) this guarantees that we are working with an array with at least 1 element. The rest of the logic confuses me. Why set i = arr.length, why a - 1 afterward? why i > 0? and --i?

Thank you

Comment: Try doing the algorithm with a simple array on a piece of paper. it will help you understand it.

Comment: If you thought about executing the algorithm from `i = 0` to `arr.length - 1`, try it on paper : you will need an extra variable or you will lose some information. Doing the loop backwards enables to get rid of this variable.

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle thank you, what does doing the loop backward mean?

Comment: @jun I mean, the fact of iterating from `i = arr.length - 1` to `i = 0` (using `i--`) instead of iterating from `i = 0` to `i = arr.length - 1` (using `i++`) .

Comment: @ArnaudDenoyelle I think I am beginning to understand it now. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`arr.length` will return the number of elements in the array. If you had an array with elements at index 0, 1, and 2, it would return "3". The problem is that the array index is inclusive at 0, so you need to subtract 1 from the length to get the valid index of the last element in the array. (ie 3 - 1 = 2 and 2 is the true index of the last element)

The loop uses `i > 0` because the index `i` is being decremented (ie i = i -1) by the '--i'.  So the loop is starting at the highest element in the array (length -1), and counting down to the lowest (index 0).

Lastly, the line assigning `toAdd` to 0 should be outside of the for loop.

Comment: Thank you. If I understand, arr.length will generate the total number of elements in the array every time by counting each occupied index. And if we have 0, 3 , 2. then 1 + 1 + 1 = 3. Now since we know the total length of the array we can use that information to find what the last index number is.
Since arr.length counts it as a human would 1,2,3,4. Whereas, the computer counts it off at 0,1,2,3,4. Then arr.length is always one ahead by one so we must delete one from arr.length to get the correct last position as the computer has counted it.

Comment: so arr.length does give the correct number of elements, but arr.length is also useful in that we can use it to get the last index by accounting for the fact that the computer counts 0,1,2,3,4 and arr.length counts 1,2,3,4 where it's right in that 1,2,3,4 will always count the right number of elements. It's great to use it as a tool to get the last index by knowing that arr.length is always on ahead of how the computer counts. So we use that information determined through arr.length as use it to get the correct last index's position number.

Comment: Or again put, arr.length will always be one ahead of how the computer counts indexes. And knowing that we can just subtract one to get it to how the computer counts index. The - 1 is just like a way of adjusting it to generate the correct last index the same way the computer would have it.

Answer (score 2):

You are browsing your array from its last element to the first, while shifting each element over by one. For example, when i = 3 we moving element 2 to position 3.

But this method doesn't work. A correct version would be:

```
public static void insert(int[] arr, int toAdd){
    if(arr.length > 0) {
        for(int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; i--) {
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
        }
        arr[0] = toAdd;
    }
}
```

`--i` reduce the value of `i` before its use so it should be `i--` or `i` should begin at `arr.length` or else you won't move the last element.

Comment: the arr[i] = arr[i - 1]; that's pretty much like saying assign the original array to everyone but back a step (i.e. - 1 step). so everyones index is traded/swapped for the one that exactly proceeded it, up until the array index is at 0, and that's when we directly sub it in.

Answer (score 0):

> Why set i = arr.length and --i?

It is `i = arr.length-1` and this the last index of the array. You have to start shifting elements looping backwards (`--i`, `i--` would be ok, too), otherwise you'll be overriding elements before you can shift them.

> why i > 0?

`arr[0] = toAdd;` should be outside of the loop and would fail for `arr.length == 0`.

You can simplify to:

```
public static void insert(int[] arr, int toAdd){
    if(arr.length > 0) {
        for(int i = arr.length - 1; i > 0; --i)
            arr[i] = arr[i - 1];
        arr[0] = toAdd;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you!
Would it then in the for loop, provided there are 6 elements go like this:

6 - 1 = 5; 5 > 0; 5 - 1 = 4

4 - 1 = 3; 3 > 0; 3 - 1 = 2

2 - 1 = 1; 1 > 0; 1 - 1 = 0

0 - 1 = -1; -1 > 0  end of loop?